# How do I deploy a Kivy GUI application as a web app in a web browser?

Tags: python, web-applications, kivy

I have developed a Kivy application and was wondering if it was possible to deploy it as a web app. I've tried using flask but it is running into some problems. I run the Kivy Application by calling the App builder class while flask does something similar. So can anyone direct me to any tutorials or other information about deploying a Kivy Application in a web browser?

I just need the GUI to display in a web browser so I believe the HTML doesn't need to be too extravagant.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to deploy a kivy app through a web browser.

Answer (score 13):

Kivy does not currently support working in a browser.

There are some experiments to do it, but the result is very slow, to open and to use, and doesn't work in all browsers; more work is needed, and it's not a priority to us. If you want a web app, use a web technology.

<sub>I am a Kivy developer</sub>

Comment: Oh bummer, but good to have a definitive answer! Have any of those experiments of the past five years borne fruit? 

Comment: that's unfortunate.. adding web could make Kivy basically cross-platform (with a browser). I'm going to try Beeware Breifcase: https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/platforms/

Comment: @alchemy kivy supports windows, linux, macOS, android, and iOS, sure that's not *all* there, is, but that's pretty cross platform imho. There might be more appeal in supporting it with pyscript these days, but it won't happen until someone works on it, regarding briefcase, feel free to try it, of course, but from what i heard recently, they do wish for more contributions on the web implementation, so i assume it's not on par with the reference (yet), also, each platform is a reimplementation, which means things will look different on web and on desktop & on handheld, it has up and downsides.

Comment: @Tshirtman, thanks for the reply. You're right, that is pretty cross-platform. I had been looking at Electron (and Neutralino) and Capactorjs, thinking a web port for Kivy could be straigtforward, but Kivy probably went the other direction.. from a Tkinkter analog to mobile. It looks like PyScript (or PyReact) to JS for Electron/Capacitor might be viable. I'll have to look how interoperable Kivy is with Pyscript. I'm casting the widest net before distilling my criteria, and Kivy is in the top 3, so thanks for the update.

Comment: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3209651/how-to-convert-python-to-javascript-and-back-again.html  Transcript maybe could interconvert.

Comment: @Tshirtman, although this is pretty much cross-platform, from a business application perspective web-app support is lacking. Corporate IT depts are not very in to maintaining desktop apps these days and prefer web applications. Therefore, I think running a kivy app in a browser window would be a great feature. The alternative for this is Anvil (TMHO) - https://anvil.works/